# Why are there wildcards with upper bounds when you can just use concrete types instead?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

Given the following class `Foo`:

```
class Foo<T extends Bar> {
    T child;
    Foo(T t) { child = t; }
}
```

Except for one difference, I do not see why I should use this class instead of a class using a concrete type like this:

```
class Foo {
    Bar child;
    Foo(Bar bar) { child = bar; }
}
```

The aforementioned difference I see is that with the generic class I can use the interface of subtypes directly (e.g. using the interface of `SubBar` if I was to instantiate the class template with `SubBar` as type parameter.) whereas with a concrete type I would have to do type checking. Is there another reason to use the generic version that I am not seeing?

Comment: @Kayaman Could you name an example where bounds would be useful then?

Comment: There's a lot of them on this site. Also note that wildcard is `?`, you have a generic parameter `T` with upper bound.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but you are no help at all. I know there are search engines; If I had found anything satisfying I would not have had to ask a question in the first place. Also I did not want to know why bounds are useful in this example but rather where they provide an advantage or where they are a necessity. I only provided classes because I was not 100% sure how I can describe my problem in words succinctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course bounds aren't always neccessary. Especially not when the superclass is all you need. But imagine implementing a sorting algorithm like Bubblesort and this algorithm should process all objects which implement the `Comparable` interface. Would it be sufficient to retrieve the ordered comparables?

I'd go with 'No'. If you throw in some Integers for example you expect a ordered list of Integers in return and not a list of Comparables.

**Example:**

```
public final class ListBubbleSort<E extends Comparable<E>>
{
  public List<E> sort(List<? extends E> list)
  {
     // do sort...
  }
}
```

Without a bound the returned list could only contain comparables which you then would have to cast yourself in order to use them as Integers again. And if not careful that could lead to a `ClassCastException`. With bounds the 'casting' is 'checked' on compiletime and therefore such an exception will become unlikely.